# Is "[I am] possessed of impeccable grammar" correct, idiomatic, or ironic?

Tags: idioms, prepositions, adjectives

If it's a correct, non-idiomatic usage, is "possessed" an adjective, or...?

What is "of" under that circumstance?

Comment: It would be ironic in the extreme if OP's statement wasn't actually grammatic, but of course it is. People are much more likely to be possessed of impeccable *taste* or *manners*, but I was surprised to find it's not a quaint "Victorianism" at all - it's a [post-war expression](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=possessed+of+impeccable&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, that's a very interesting tool--I like that. I'd be curious to see that graphed against the number of books available.

Comment: [BNC](http://corpus.byu.edu/bnc/) (British) and [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) (American) are more "selective, representative" searchable [corpora](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/corpus), but I find Google's NGram more accessible - plus it does nice charts for getting a point across succinctly here on ELU.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Toys! And I didn't get you anything :( What fun; thanks.

Comment: Apart from my two front teeth, all I want for Christmas is 25K on ELU :)

Comment: One thing I never understand and I don't know whether it's mistake or not but people claiming to be in possession of grammar. Wouldn't it make far more sense to utilise proper grammar as opposed to owning it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[Possessed of](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/possessed_of)* as a unit is classified as an adjective meaning *possessing*, which [Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/possessed) calls an idiom. *Of* is a preposition added in order to make the idiom.  Compare it with *I am possessed **by** impeccable grammar*: this makes use of the normal meaning of *possessed*.  *Possessed* is usually the past participle of *possess* (so it usually means *owned*).  However, when you add the preposition *of*, *possessed of* no longer means *owned*, it means *owning*.

So *I am possessed of impeccable grammar* is interpreted *I am possessing impeccable grammar* (idiomatic interpretation), rather than *I am owned by impeccable grammar* (normal interpretation, overridden by the idiom).

Answer (score 1):

["Possessed of" means "own" or "have"](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/possessed_of). So "I am possessed of impeccable grammar" means "I have impeccable grammar".

Comment: Okay; thanks. I know what it means, just wanted it broken down.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds excessively formal but not wrong to me. *Possessed* is a past participle, or an adjective, if you prefer, and *of* is a preposition; if you want to classify phrases by part of speech, then I'd call *possessed of* a preposition, simply because it acts like one, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0):

“To be possessed of” in the sense “to be in possession of” is listed in the OED, art. “possess” 9, with a fair number of citations ranging from 1440 to 2002. It is thus certainly not incorrect, perhaps no longer idiomatic, quite possibly (in a modern context) ironic.